# jquery mouseover contradict with css hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, addclass, blur

I have a hover event applying to input text field in my css, but I also have a blur event applying to the same element. Since these two events will not happen at the same time, so I believe that it makes sense to use two events and have totally different effect when the event happens. Somehow, only css event works so far. But jquery works before, and it stops working since I added the css parts.

To be more sepicified, there is a hover event in the css, the border of input text field will become blue when mouse hover it. But I also have another event in jquery, when user put negative number into the input text field , it will have the alter and the border of the input text filed will become red. 
Somehow, the jquery part is not working~ 
Help!!!!

HTML:

```
<div class="roundcorner">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Out of 100 points how would you score Governemnt performance for each section.</th>
            <th>Most like to see increased</th>
            <th>Most willing to see decreased</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="p2">
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
                <td id="i1">lakdksakdmksa</td>
                <td id="d1">
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" />Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="p2">
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
                <td id="i2">dsfwsedfwefwe</td>
                <td id="d2">
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" />No</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
```

CSS:

```
.roundcorner {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.roundcorner table {
    // border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
th {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}
td {
    text-align: centre;
    //border: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}
tr:hover {
    background: #fafafa;
    // font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 45%;
}
input[type=text] {
    width:20%;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-right:40%;
    border-radius:3px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

input[type=text]:hover{
     border: 1px solid #0066FF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

td:first-child {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    height:60px;
}

.inputbox {
    border: 1px solid #8FDAFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.error{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input:text").blur(function(event){
            if(event.which != 8){
                if(document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")).value < 0){
                    alert("Please do no put negative number.");
                    document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")).value=0;
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                }




            }

        }); 


});
```

UPDATED Link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/4hwwqr73/

Comment: The JS in your example doesn't even work if the CSS is removed.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it, but I don't know why this JS part not working.

Comment: Part of the problem is `document.getElementById($(this).attr("id"))`. `this` will be a text input within the handler, and none of your inputs have an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the JS not working in your example, you are dealing with a [specificity issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

You are setting the initial border with the selector `input[type=text]`, which has a specificity calculation of 11. (Element = 1, attribute selector = 10).

When hovering over the element, you are using the selector `input[type=text]:hover` which has a specificity of 21 (Element = 1, attribute selector = 10, pseudo class = 10).

The class `error` only has a specificity of 10, which means that the red border is therefore not applied. To solve this, you could use a more specific selector:

```
input[type=text].error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    outline: none;
}
```

It's worth noting that the selector has the same specificity as `input[type=text].error`. But since `input[type=text].error` precedes it in order, *it* is applied. (That's the cascade nature).

Since this was tagged with jQuery, though, I think you want something along these lines:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    0 > parseInt(this.value) && $(this).addClass("error");
});
```

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/btuyf9pw/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a close look at the specificity issue page mentioned in your answer. However, I still don't understand how you calculate the points, such as  (Element = 1, attribute selector = 10, pseudo class = 10), and they are not declared in the specificity issue page. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, Josh, I kind of get how you calculate the specificity now. There are a, b, c, d sections, a has higher priority than b, and b is higher  than c, and so on. a represents inline style, b represents IDs, c is Classes, Attributes, and Pseudo-classes, d is Element Types and Pseudo-elements. You used 10 as unit. For input[type="text"].error, it has specificity as 0,0,2,1, that is 21. For input[type="text"]:hover, whose specificity is 0, 0, 1, 2, equal to 12, for .error, whose specificity is 0, 0, 1, 0, = 10. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I got my conclusion from : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity

Comment: However, I don't understand what is the difference between pseudo-class and pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").blur(function(event){
        var TheValue = $(this).val();
        if( TheValue > 0 ){
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            // Do something here
        }else{
           alert("Please do no put negative number.");
           $(this).addClass('error');
           return false;
        }
    }); 
});
```

and your css add important

```
.error{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
 }
```

Comment: It might work, but !important is not a good practice , because it breaks the cascading nature. Anyway, thanks for your answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Or try this similar to your script:

```
$("input:text").blur(function(event, x){
    if(event.which != 8){
        if(parseInt(this.value) < 0){
            alert("Please do no put negative number.");
            this.value = 0;
            $(this).parent().addClass('error')
        }else{
            $(this).parent().removeClass('error')
        }
    }
});
```